# How to process frames of an existing video in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avfoundation

Currently I am trying to process the frames of an existing video with OpenCV. Are there any AV reader libraries that contain delegate methods that process frames while playing back videos? I know how to process frames during a live AVCaptureSession through the use of the AVCaptureVideoDataOutput and the captureOutput delegate method. Is there something similar for playing back videos?

Any help would be appreiciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVAssetReader / AVAssetReaderOutput are what you're looking for.  Check out the CopyNextSampleBuffer method.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetreaderoutput

Comment: Thanks Tim! I ended up getting it to work with an AVAssetReader.

Comment: Hi @NFarrell, it'll be very helpful if you can upload you solution, i'm having some issues with getting this to work based on using the apple documentation for AVAssetReader

Comment: Hi @Vivian_S.O. Yea I can dig for the solution and update my answer. That was a long time ago though so I'm not sure if it exists anymore though

Answer (score 3):

Here's the solution. Thanks to Tim Bull's answer I accomplished this using AVAssetReader / AssetReaderOutput

The below function I called within a button click to start the video, and begin processing each frame with OpenCV:

```
func processVids() {
    guard let pathOfOrigVid = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "output_10_34_34", ofType: "mp4") else{
        print("video.m4v not found\n")
        exit(0)
    }
    
    var path: URL? = nil

    do{
        path = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        path = path?.appendingPathComponent("grayVideo.mp4")
    }catch{
        print("Unable to make URL to Movies path\n")
        exit(0)
    }
    
    
    let movie: AVURLAsset = AVURLAsset(url: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: pathOfOrigVid) as URL, options: nil)
    let tracks: [AVAssetTrack] = movie.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)
    let track: AVAssetTrack = tracks[0]
    var reader: AVAssetReader? = nil
    do{
        reader = try AVAssetReader(asset: movie)
    }
    catch{
        print("Problem initializing AVReader\n")
    }
    
    let settings : [String: Any?] = [
        String(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32ARGB),
        String(kCVPixelBufferIOSurfacePropertiesKey): [:]
    ]

    let rout: AVAssetReaderTrackOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track, outputSettings: settings)
    reader?.add(rout)
    reader?.startReading()
    
    
    DispatchQueue.global().async(execute: {
        while reader?.status == AVAssetReaderStatus.reading {
            if(rout.copyNextSampleBuffer() != nil){

                // Buffer of the frame to perform OpenCV processing on
                let sbuff: CMSampleBuffer = rout.copyNextSampleBuffer()!    
                
            }
            usleep(10000)
        }
        
    })
   
}
```

Comment: Here's the solution I came up with @Vivian_S.O. hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AVVideoComposition`

If You want to process frames with `CoreImage` you can create an instance by calling `init(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:)` method.

Or you can create custom comopsitor

> You can implement your own custom video compositor by implementing the
>   AVVideoCompositing  protocol; a custom video compositor is provided
>   with pixel buffers for each of its video sources during playback and
>   other operations and can perform arbitrary graphical operations on
>   them in order to produce visual output.

See [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideocomposition) for more info.
[Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/AVCustomEdit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013411-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) you can find an example (but example is in Objective-C).

Comment: Hello Tiko thanks for the input. I ended up getting it to work with an AVAssetReader.

Answer (score 1):

For someone need to process frame of video by OpenCV.

Decode video:

```
@objc public protocol ARVideoReaderDelegate : NSObjectProtocol {
    func reader(_ reader:ARVideoReader!, newFrameReady sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer?, _ frameCount:Int)
    func readerDidFinished(_ reader:ARVideoReader!, totalFrameCount:Int)
}
@objc open class ARVideoReader: NSObject {
    var _asset: AVURLAsset!
    @objc var _delegate: ARVideoReaderDelegate?

    @objc public init!(urlAsset asset:AVURLAsset){
        _asset = asset
        super.init()
    }

    @objc open func startReading() -> Void {
        if let reader = try? AVAssetReader.init(asset: _asset){

            let videoTrack = _asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).compactMap{ $0 }.first;
            let options = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey : Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
            let readerOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput.init(track: videoTrack!, outputSettings: options as [String : Any])
            reader.add(readerOutput)
            reader.startReading()

            var count = 0
            //reading
            while (reader.status == .reading && videoTrack?.nominalFrameRate != 0){
                let sampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer()
                _delegate?.reader(self, newFrameReady: sampleBuffer, count)
                count = count+1;
            }
            _delegate?.readerDidFinished(self,totalFrameCount: count)
        }
    }
}
```

In the callback of delegate:

```
//convert sampleBuffer to cv::Mat
CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);
CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
char *baseBuffer = (char*)CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

cv::Mat cvImage = cv::Mat((int)height,(int)width,CV_8UC3);

cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> it_start = cvImage.begin<cv::Vec3b>();
cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> it_end = cvImage.end<cv::Vec3b>();
long cur = 0;
size_t padding = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer) - width*4;
size_t offset = padding;
while (it_start != it_end) {
    //opt pixel
    long p_idx = cur*4 + offset;
    char b = baseBuffer[p_idx];
    char g = baseBuffer[p_idx + 1];
    char r = baseBuffer[p_idx + 2];
    cv::Vec3b newpixel(b,g,r);
    *it_start = newpixel;
    cur++;
    it_start++;
    if (cur%width == 0) {
        offset = offset + padding;
    }
}
CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, kCVPixelBufferLock_ReadOnly);
//process cvImage now
```